# What the difference between Bose-Einstein condensate and quantum spin liquid?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, states-of-matter

When matter gets close to absolute zero temperature, how does it becomes either BEC or QSL? I know in BEC atoms lose their individual id and becomes super-atom and as for spin liquid the alignment of electrons are in disarray at such low temperature instead of becoming magnetic like superconducting magnet super roughly speaking. I just want to know how do matter knows which of the above mentioned state to becomes at near absolute zero? I am a curious layman so please use jargon sparingly and excuse my grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by "electrons are in disarray"?

Comment: Matter close to absolute zero temperature usually forms a crystal lattice of atoms. Anything else (like, e.g. a BEC) is a meta stable state requiring varying degrees of experimental finesse to create. The only real exception is helium, which forms a superfluid at low temperatures due its small mass.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a layman too, but this is how i understand Wikipedia:

In a [BEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate), the bosons (force-carrying glue particles) that keep the fermions (particles that can't share space) together cooperate to have no viscosity or electrical resistance. Made from simple atoms like 4He.

In [QSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_spin_liquid), electrons [divide](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3522827/Mysterious-new-state-matter-discovered-Quantum-spin-liquid-seen-real-world-material-40-YEARS-predicted-make-computers-superfast.html) into entangled Majorana fermions. Seen in complex molecules like Na4Ir3O8 that might make more stable qubits, as told by [real scientists](https://youtu.be/XHUgetdkJmg?t=2m9s) and [this dude's trippy video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wxf7sALcrt4).

Put simply, BEC unifies force particles and QSL unifies mass particles.

Comment: This answer is non sensical and inaccurate. The bosons in a BEC do not have to be carrying any force at all. Neutral atoms are routinely brought into the bec state, and they can hardly be considered as force particles. The distinction between these two types of matter has nothing to do with mass.

Comment: Are bosons not force-carrying glue particles?